# Krita on two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, images, tablet, drawing, krita

My problem is related to the fact that i have two the same (1920x1080) monitors connected and want to work on a single monitor with krita. So the fact is that the whole area of my tablet is mapped to both monitors, not the single one. Simply speaking here is what I need using an image:

[image]

My tablet is "One by Wacom". Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that the tablet settings include such a setting in the "mapping" tab, I didn't see before:
[image]